# animating a body and having it effect cloth

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

I have a body I've created and put clothes on him.  I gave them a cloth modifier and him a collision modifier.  When I simulate the cloth it falls on the body and reacts like cloth, however if I animate the body, it goes through the cloth is there something that I need to do to make the cloth keep reacting to the body as it is animated?

Answer (score 1):

You could try pinning the mesh and make a parent relation to your main body, it will then follow the body you modeled, take a look at this explanation on how it works:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/cloth/settings/cloth_settings.html#cloth

Have a nice day.